# how to remove a button when clicked / click the button replace time in php

Tags: php, html, forms, datetime

how to remove a button when clicked / click the button replace time in php

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <button name="click" class="click">Click me!</button>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST["click"])){
     $currentDateTime = new \DateTime();
     //set timeZone
     $currentDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Singapore'));
     $dateTime = $currentDateTime->format('H:i');
     echo $dateTime;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I assume you mean without reloading the page? You'll have to use JavaScript. PHP runs on the server, JavaScript runs in the browser. Depending on exactly what you want to do, you can probably do the entire replacing thing with JS and avoid making an ajax request to your PHP

Comment: What specifically isn't working?  Are you successfully outputting the date/time and just need to also hide the button?  If so, it sounds like you want to make use of the `if` statement you already have.

Comment: yes i want to hide the button

Comment: i have tried Javascript... but doesn't work.. I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I think you are telling about this:*

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["click"])){
     $currentDateTime = new \DateTime();
     //set timeZone
     $currentDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Singapore'));
     $dateTime = $currentDateTime->format('H:i');
     echo $dateTime;
    }else{echo '<form action="" method="POST"><button name="click" class="click">Click me!</button></form>';}
    ?>
```